# How to loop over a nested object using Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have the following json:

```
{'classifications':
  [
    {
      'sports': 
        [
          {'soccer':[{'coach':'John'}]}
          {'tennis':[{'coach':'Peter'},{'coach':'Paul'}]}
        ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to ngFor to generate divs for each of the "Sports" and also a sublist of each of the "Coaches".

How do I do this? When I try:

```
<div  *ngFor="let sport of myobj.classifications[0].sports;let i = index;">
{{sport}}
</div>
```

I am getting errors saying that classifications[0] is undefined... When I just leave it as myobj.classifications and iterate over that, no errors are returned. How do I properly access this?

Comment: It's probably undefined while you're fetching it from the backend, before the response comes back. Wrap everything with `<div *ngIf="classifications.length">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a safe navigation/ elvis operator to check if the data is present,

change it as

```
<div  *ngFor="let sport of myobj?.classifications[0]?.sports;let i = index;">
{{sport}}
</div>
```

Comment: Am getting a  Cannot read property '0' of undefined... I see in the JSON object I have that classifications key does exist, no typos. Suspecting it is undefined initially because it has to come over ajax?

Comment: @Rolando yeah thats the issue! try this "let sport of myobj?.classifications?classifications[0].sports;let i = index;"